# VBA Byte Array to String

Tags: string, vba, byte, arrays

Apologies if this question has been previously answered, I was unable to find an explanation. I've created a script in VBScript to encrypt an user input and match to an already encrypted password. I ran into some issues along the way and managed to deduce to the following.

I have a byte array (1 to 2) as values (1, 16). I am then defining a string with the value of the array as per below:

```
Dim bytArr(1 To 2) As Byte
Dim output As String
bytArr(1) = 16
bytArr(2) = 1

output = bytArr
Debug.Print output
```

The output I get is Ð (Eth) ASCII Value 208. Could someone please explain how the byte array is converted to this character?

Answer (score 1):

- In VBA, Byte Arrays are special because, unlike arrays of other datatypes, a [string can be directly assigned to a byte array](https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/06/06/vba-trick-of-the-week-byte-array-in-vba/). In VBA, Strings are UNICODE strings, so when one assigns a string to a byte array then it stores two digits for each character;
- although the glyphs seem to be the same, see `charmap`:

  - **Ð** is [Unicode Character 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER ETH' (U+00D0)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00d0/index.htm) shown in `charmap` DOS Western (Central) Europe character set (`0xD1`, i.e. decimal `209`);
  - **Đ** is [Unicode Character 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D WITH STROKE' (U+0110)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0110/index.htm) shown in `charmap` Windows Western (Central Europe) character set (`0xD0`, i.e. decimal `208`).

Get above statements together keeping in mind [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (byte order) of the computer architecture: Intel x86 processors use little-endian, so byte array (`0x10`, `0x01`) is the same as unicode string `U+0110`.

Charaters are *amalgamated* via flagrant [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case. For proof, please use [`Asc` and `AscW` Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zew1e4wc(v=vs.90).aspx) as follows: `Debug.Print output, Asc(output), AscW(output)` with different console code pages, e.g. under `chcp 852` and `chcp 1250`.

Comment: Hi JosefZ,

Thanks for the input, however I'm not sure I fully understand. When i run the script as per the above I receive the output from 'output = bytArr' as 208. I assumed this related to the ASCII value and therefore corresponded with the lowercase eth (208) however if I attempted to show the character by altering the script it would show capital letter eth (209).

Could you please explain exactly how the array 16, 1 is amalgamated to create the value 208?